# My HD 5670 is fake?

Tags: gpu, amd-radeon

I was reading some of the specs of the new 5670 I got my hands on and it says "Does not require PCI-e power connector" or something like that. In reality, it does have a power plug. Also, there's some weird thing with the naming. Look at the pictures:

[image]

It does not say "5670" unlike the most screenshots I've seen online. Another anomaly is the memory clock which is 667MHz. I've read that it comes with 1000MHz from the factory.

And it also differs from the AMD specifications:

[image]

627M transistors is the spec while I have 1040M transistors.

400 stream procs is the spec while I have 620 stream procs.

5670 GPU's name is Redwood XT while mine is Juniper(which is 5770's GPU's name btw)

Conclusion: What is going on with my card?

NOTE: The card is a PowerColor HD 5670 2GB. I bought it from a local computer shop which is well-known.

Answer (score 0):

Most GPUs today is able to dynamically change core and memory frequency to save power. It will only reach the rated frequency when you're watching video or running 3D apps.

Also, GPU-Z is not able to read the number of transistors from the chip. It all come from a built-in database that maps the hardware id to the chip data. If the hardware id does not show that actual variant of the chip used, then the data is not relevant. Number of transistors translates to die size (under the same technology node) which translated to cost, I don't think they will give you a higher end chip to save money. The data in GPU-Z probably only reflect the highest end chip HD5750 in the HD5600/5700 series.

Comment: The problem is Crysis was running in the background when I took that screenshot. Also then why is the hardware id different?